# trying to make my sql communicate with jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mysql-workbench

am getting the error below when running the query

(QUERY)%sql mysql+pymysql://root:Fena.3250@localhost:3306/united_nations

(ERROR MESSAGE)
MetaData.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

i EXPECTED IT TO CONNECT

Answer (score 0):

run pip install --user sqlalchemy==1.4.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).